# Bootstrap 2 - Built-in Collapse-Menu (Narrow Screen) - How to Change Color of Links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need the links in my navbar to be a different color, background-color, and width on the collapse-menu listing than they are in the wide-screen menu-display.

I can set all these css properties easily in a way that they are applied to BOTH menus, but cannot figure out how to affect ONLY the collapse-view (nav-button-clicked) version.

I see the class 'on' is added to the parent-div when the nav-button is clicked (firebug), but applying css using this class has no effect - and the css under this class does not appear in 'inspect' for the items or parents.

I have not altered the basic bootstrap navbar format.  To be specific, the items in question are within:

```
<!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
    <li> My Link 1 Is Here </li>
    <li> My Link 2 Is Here </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check the media queries on the CSS

Comment: Ah, I was looking for a different class or something to set.  Putting that code in the max-width setting that corresponds with when the navbar switches modes did the trick.  Thanks.